# Ubuntu 19.10 Search Box in GNOME is not working

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

I'm currently using Ubuntu 19.10. Search box in Ubuntu finds no app:
[image: Search box problem]

In fact nothing shows up. Does someone know some procedure to debug this?

Comment: I searched for "google" because have google chrome installed. Yes the same thing happen when i search for "Firefox" and any other programs. By the way this happen with any word searched...

Comment: DIsable any Gnome Shell extensions for a start, then log out and back in. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: @vanadium I've found a solution similar to what you indicated, i'm editing my question to help who needs. Thanks !

Comment: Possibly related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237242/search-bar-not-showing-results/1358881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem. In my case, the cause was a script from gnome-look for edit GDM theme, some incompatibility happens in ubuntu 19.10 and this script. For solve this problem just reinstall the yaru theme

```bsh
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

Then reboot or press alt+f2 with r for reload GNOME.