# Search bar not showing results

Tags: gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

Dash doesn't show any results but the results are being generated in the background since when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> I get the first result opened (see screenshot, if I press <kbd>enter</kbd> it would open Terminal).

[image]

This has been going on over 2 dist upgrades now and I tried reinstalling every possible related package and delete cache numerous times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Applications are not showing after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230515/my-applications-are-not-showing-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04)

Comment: Nope I've tried that with numerous restarts, same issue with all extensions disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Folders included for search can be selected manually in “settings” > “search” > “search locations”. Please adjust the settings such that your files are indexed.

When selecting large folders, indexing could take a while. This can be seen by running `$ tracker status`. When indexing finished, run r in command window (alt+F2).

Relevant GNOME issue page: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/78